# Can't remove product list toolbar

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, home, toolbar

I am using Porto Theme and I'm trying to remove product tool bar from the home page but it isn't working. My Magento version is 1.9.2.4.

I'm using [this method by Anders Wik](http://www.anderswik.se/magento/2014/12/01/Magento-Remove-Toolbar.html)

My theme configuration:

[image]

I also did it:

[image]

I've copied

```
app/design/frontend/smartwave/porto/layout/local.xml
```

to

```
app/design/frontend/smartwave/criaseo/layout/local.xml
```

and I also copied

```
app/design/frontend/smartwave/porto/template/catalog/product/list.phtml
```

to

```
 app/design/frontend/smartwave/criaseo/template/catalog/product/list.phtml
```

But the toolbar is still there!!!

Here is the original local.xml of my theme:

```
<cms_index_index>
    <update handle="MAP_popup"/>
    <reference name="top.container">
        <block type="core/template" name="home_slider">
            <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="homeslider/general/slider_type" condition="0"><template>homeslider/home_slider.phtml</template></action>
        </block>
        <remove name="pageHeader"/>
    </reference>
    <reference name="after_body_start">
        <block type="core/template" name="home_slider">
            <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="homeslider/general/slider_type" condition="1"><template>homeslider/home_slider_top.phtml</template></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
    <reference name="newsletter_popup">
        <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="porto_settings/newsletter_popup/enabled" condition="1"><template>newsletter/popup.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

This is where I want to remove the toolbar. Only on the home page.

It will be great if anyone could tell me where I am doing wrong here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try to remove your toolbar right after your handle

```
<cms_index_index>
   <remove name="your.toolbar.name"/>
</cms_index_index>
```

But care, it will be remove on all your cms pages.
To avoid it, you have to create a custom handle specially for your home page

https://gist.github.com/0-Sony/c075a17edfb5f26c5082

and remove the toolbar in this custom homepage handle